# How to use Iconsax icons in css format

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons

I downloaded iconsax icons packages in css format, I am unable to find any ways to use them also im new to web dev section.
I have never used any icons pack up until now. This is my first time using package.

After some searching i found most of icon packages use this format to show the icons:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/icon-css-style.css">
</head>

<i class="icon-add-circle"></i>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For me, the iconsax package is not working either. I have referenced the css file in my <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"> </head> and I am using it like this: <span class="isax isax-video"></span>, but it seems like, the svg-file is broken

Answer (score 1):

I use this package with React and I have no problem. I import the style.css file with the fonts folder then I use the following syntax: `<i className="isax isax-square"></i>`.

The icon is not broken.